# Adding additional label value when clicked on Sankey Chart lines in R shiny

Tags: r, plotly, shiny, sankey-diagram

The following R shiny script creates a sankey chart as in the snapshot below. My requirement is that when I click on any link between the nodes on left and right i.e. "a1" and "a2", I want the total sum of corresponding "a3" to be present in the label. For Illustration, "A" in a1 and "E" in a2 together have value 50 and 32. So, I want to see 82 in the label when clicked on link, please help and thanks. Similary for all other a1,a2 pairs. Some tweak is needed in the list() function in server code below. Attaching the snapshot.

```
library(shiny)
library(shinydashboard)
library(plotly)
library(DT)
library(dplyr)
a1 = c("A","B","C","A","C","C","B")
a2 = c("E","F","G","E","G","G","F")
a3 = c(50,45,64,32,45,65,75)
a12 = data.frame(a1,a2,a3,stringsAsFactors = FALSE)
a12$a1 = as.character(a12$a1)
a12$a2 = as.character(a12$a2)
ui <- dashboardPage(
dashboardHeader(title = "Sankey Chart"),
dashboardSidebar(
width = 0
),
dashboardBody(
box(title = "Sankey Chart", status = "primary",height = "455" ,solidHeader = 
T,plotlyOutput("sankey_plot")),
box( title = "Case Summary", status = "primary", height = "455",solidHeader 
= T, dataTableOutput("sankey_table"))
))
server <- function(input, output) 
{ 
sankeyData <- reactive({
sankeyData <- a12 %>% 
  group_by(a1,a2) %>% 
  count()
sankeyNodes <- list(label = c(sankeyData$a1,sankeyData$a2) %>% unique())
trace2 <- list(
  domain = list(
    x = c(0, 1), 
    y = c(0, 1)
  ), 
  link = list(
    label = paste0("Case",1:nrow(sankeyData)), 
    source = sapply(sankeyData$a1,function(e) {which(e == 
                                                       sankeyNodes$label) }, 
   USE.NAMES = FALSE) - 1, 
    target = sapply(sankeyData$a2,function(e) {which(e == 
                                                       sankeyNodes$label) }, 
    USE.NAMES = FALSE) - 1, 
    value = sankeyData$n
  ), 
  node = list(label = sankeyNodes$label), 
  type = "sankey"
  )
  trace2
  })
  output$sankey_plot <- renderPlotly({
  trace2 <- sankeyData()
  p <- plot_ly()
  p <- add_trace(p, domain=trace2$domain, link=trace2$link, 
               node=trace2$node, type=trace2$type)
  p
  })
  output$sankey_table <- renderDataTable({
  d <- event_data("plotly_click")
  req(d)
  trace2 <- sankeyData()
  sIdx <-  trace2$link$source[d$pointNumber+1]
  Source <- trace2$node$label[sIdx + 1 ]
  tIdx <- trace2$link$target[d$pointNumber+1]
  Target <- trace2$node$label[tIdx+1]
  a12 %>% filter(a1 == Source & a2 == Target)
  })
  }
  shinyApp(ui, server)
```

[image: Sankey Plot]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I guess the solution you need is

```
value = apply(t(sankeyData),2, function(e, Vals){
           e <- data.frame(t(e), stringsAsFactors = FALSE)
           sum(Vals[which(e$a1 == Vals$a1 & e$a2 == Vals$a2),3])
         }, Vals = a12)
```

instead of

```
value = sankeyData$n
```

With this you get something like this:

[image]

Hope it helps!

Comment: Thanks this is good, but if can please arrange the sum value below the Target, that previous value is the count of all the items. Thanks.

Comment: You mean you want the sum to be displayed below the Target?

Comment: Yes Please, below the Target.

Comment: The R plotly skankey diagram does not seem to have that provision. One thing that can be done is adding it before the source.

Comment: thank you so much for the help, kindly suggest if you come across anything in this regard.

Comment: I am using your solution in a large dataset, I would kindly request if you can kindly make this solution code above a little faster by modifying it a little, thanks and please help.

Comment: @AdamShaw If you need, you can print the same below your `Case`