# Shiny: selectInput based on previous selectInput resetting the selected value

Tags: r, shiny, selectinput

There are several questions on this issue, including [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48519138/selectinput-value-update-based-on-previous-selectinput-in-r-shiny), but I am still not sure what I need to change to get this right.

The selectInput choices are working as expected, other than when I change the second selectInput, it temporarily changes to the desired selection but then automatically goes back to the first filtered selection.

For example, if "gear" is chosen for `Variable 1`, then the `Variable 1 choices` correctly display "3, 4, 5" for possible gear choices.  If I select "5" for gear, it briefly shows up and then goes back to gear "3" as a choice.  I am not sure how to prevent that reactive behavior.

Here is a simple reproducible example using the mtcars built-in data set:

```
library(tidyverse)
library(shiny)



# Variables interested in selecting
my_vars <- c("cyl", "gear", "carb")



# UI
ui <- fluidPage(
  
  # Title
  titlePanel("Reprex"),
  
  # Sidebar 
  sidebarLayout(
    sidebarPanel(
                 selectInput("sel_1",
                             "Variable 1",
                             choices  = my_vars,
                             selected = my_vars[[1]],
                             multiple = FALSE
                 ),
                 selectInput("sel_2",
                             "Variable 1 choices",
                             choices  = unique(mtcars[[ my_vars[[1]] ]]),
                             multiple = FALSE
                 )
    ), # sidebarPanel close
    
    # Plot
    mainPanel(
      plotOutput("plot_out")
    )  # mainPanel close
  )    # sidebarLayout close
)      # UI close




# Server
server <- function(input, output, session) {
  
  output$plot_out <- renderPlot({
    
    # Assign inputs
    sel_1 <- input$sel_1
    sel_2 <- input$sel_2
    
    
    # Make drop-down choice of sel_2 dependent upon user input of sel_1
    # *** Must put "shiny::observe" instead of "observe" since "observe" is masked by the Tidy infer package ***
    shiny::observe({
      updateSelectInput(session,
                        "sel_2",
                        choices = sort(unique(mtcars[[sel_1]]))
                        )
    })
    
    
    
    # Data to plot
    my_data <- mtcars %>% 
      filter(.data[[sel_1]] == sel_2)

    
    
    # Plot
    p <- ggplot(my_data, aes(x = factor(.data[[sel_1]]), y = hp)) + geom_point()
    p
    
  })
}




# Run the application 
shinyApp(ui = ui, server = server)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That's because your observer is inside the `renderPlot`. It has nothing to do here.

```
server <- function(input, output, session) {

  # Make drop-down choice of sel_2 dependent upon user input of sel_1
  observeEvent(input$sel_1, {
    updateSelectInput(session,
                      "sel_2",
                      choices = sort(unique(mtcars[[input$sel_1]]))
    )
  })
  
  output$plot_out <- renderPlot({
    
    # Assign inputs
    sel_1 <- input$sel_1
    sel_2 <- input$sel_2
    
    # Data to plot
    my_data <- mtcars %>% 
      filter(.data[[sel_1]] == sel_2)
    
    # Plot
    ggplot(my_data, aes(x = factor(.data[[sel_1]]), y = hp)) + geom_point()

  })
}
```

Here the `observeEvent` instead of `observe` is not necessary, since `input$sel_1` is the only reactive value inside the observer, but I find that `observeEvent` is more readable.

Also, avoid to load **tidyverse**. That loads a ton of packages you don't need. Here **dplyr** and **ggplot2** are enough

Comment: Agree that `observeEvent` is more clear.  Thanks for pointing out the issue with having the reactive (observe) within another reactive (renderPlot)